# How to do the same feature/function in jquery from mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools

```
//new tmp element that contains the new div
var tmpDiv = new Element('div',{html:'<div id="video"><iframe title="YouTube video player" width="370" height="208" src="'+video+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>'});
//new div (first child of my tmp div) replaces the old 'myDiv' (that can be grabbed from the DOM by $)
tmpDiv.getFirst().replaces($('video'));


$$('.showing').removeClass('showing');
$('thumb-' + id).addClass('showing');
```

How could I convert this to jquery?  I believe it is using the mootools dynamic library.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading this right, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$("#video").replaceWith('<div id="video"><iframe title="YouTube video player" width="370" height="208" src="'+video+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');

$('.showing').removeClass('showing');
$('#thumb-' + id).addClass('showing');
```